# How to test Either from Arrow in functional style

Tags: junit, kotlin, functional-programming, either, arrow-kt

I would like to test the obtained result using Either. Let's assume I have a simple example without Either

```
@Test
fun `test arithmetic`() {
    val simpleResult = 2 + 2
    Assertions.assertEquals(4, simpleResult)
}
```

And now i have wrapped result:

```
@Test
fun `test arithmetic with either`() {
    val result : Either<Nothing, Int> = (2 + 2).right()
    Assertions.assertTrue(result.isRight())
    result.map { Assertions.assertEquals(4, it) }
}
```

I suppose it looks a little bit ugly, because the last Assertions will not be executed if we got `Either.Left` instead of `Either.Right` 
How can I test the result properly in functional style?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[kotlintest](https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest) provides a `kotest-assertions-arrow` module which can be used to test Arrow types.

It basically expose matchers for Either and other data type. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest/blob/master/kotest-assertions/kotest-assertions-arrow/src/jvmMain/kotlin/io/kotest/assertions/arrow/either/matchers.kt).

```
@Test
fun `test arithmetic with either`() {
    val result : Either<Nothing, Int> = (2 + 2).right()
    result.shouldBeRight(4)
}
```

Comment: WARNING: this has been removed in recent versions of kotest-assertions-arrow

Answer (score 5):

The implementations of `Either` are data classes on both sides so you can do something like:

```
check(result == 4.right())
```

Or can use something similar with any other assertion library that uses `equals` to assert equality.

Answer (score 0):

You can create extension functions:

```
fun <L, R> Either<L, R>.assertIsLeft(): L {
    return when (this) {
        is Either.Left -> value
        is Either.Right -> throw AssertionError("Expected Either.Left, but found Either.Right with value $value")
    }
}

fun <L, R> Either<L, R>.assertIsRight(): R {
    return when (this) {
        is Either.Right -> value
        is Either.Left -> throw AssertionError("Expected Either.Right, but found Either.Left with value $value")
    }
}

fun <T: Any> T.assertEqualsTo(expected: T): Boolean {
    return this == expected
}
```

With them you tests could look like these:

```
val resultRight : Either<Nothing, Int> = (2 + 2).right()
resultRight
    .assertIsRight()
    .assertEqualsTo(4)

val resultLeft: Either<RuntimeException, Nothing> = RuntimeException("Some exception cause").left()
resultLeft
    .assertIsLeft()
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using [Google Truth library](https://truth.dev/), you can create these extensions:

```
import com.google.common.truth.Subject
import arrow.core.Either

fun Subject.isRight(){
    return this.isInstanceOf(Either.Right::class.java)
}
 
fun Subject.isLeft(){
    return this.isInstanceOf(Either.Left::class.java)
}
```

Then use it in your tests:

```
import com.google.common.truth.Truth.assertThat
import arrow.core.Either
 
@Test
fun `assert right`(){
    val result: Either<String, Unit> = getResult()
    assertThat(result).isRight()
}
 
@Test
fun `assert left`(){
    val result: Either<String, Unit> = getResult()
    assertThat(result).isLeft()
}
```

or if you want to check for specific values in `Left` or `Right`:

```
import com.google.common.truth.Truth.assertThat
import arrow.core.right
import arrow.core.left
import arrow.core.Either
 
@Test
fun `assert right`(){
    val result: Either<String, String> = Either.Right("test-string")
    assertThat(result).isEqualTo("test-string".right())
}
 
@Test
fun `assert left`(){
    val result: Either<String, String> = Either.Left("test-string")
    assertThat(result).isEqualTo("test-string".left())
}
```